# How to specify a HUB in my RSS to conform with WebSub?

Tags: xml, rss, websub

I have RSS feed. I want to update information about my post instantly with WebSub server. I chose Google Free server https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/. There is an instruction on server's main page:

> Add an //atom:link tag under //atom:feed for Atom feeds or under
> //rss:rss/channel for RSS feeds. The //atom:link tag should have rel
> attribute set to hub and href attribute set to
> https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/

I do not understand what `or under //rss:rss/channel for RSS feeds` means? According to instruction I have to add a link to channel section of my `feed.xml`. But I do not understand how this link should look like?

I found the example for atom feed [here](https://podnews.net/article/pubsubhubbub-for-podcasters). The atom link should look like this:

```
<link rel="hub" href="https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" />
```

Can't find any example for RSS feed. Any thoughts?

This is an example of my feed.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">

    <channel>
        <title>Примеры фида RSS в Google Новостях</title>

        <link>https://www.mysite.ua/static/rss/newsline.xml</link>

        <description>Это примеры фида RSS в Google Новостях.</description>

        <lastBuildDate>Fri, 23 Jan 2015 23:26:19 +0000</lastBuildDate>

        <item>

            <guid>https://mysite.ua/url-post.html</guid>

            <pubDate>Fri, 23 Jan 2015 23:17:00 +0000</pubDate>

            <title>Example 1</title>

            <description>Desc</description>

            <content:encoded>

                <![CDATA[<p>Lorem ipsum dolor ]]>

            </content:encoded>

            <link>http://examples.com/sample-post.html</link>

            <author>pochta@example.com (Anna Name)</author>

            <enclosure url="https://examples.com/img/1300x820.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="0"/>

        </item>

    </channel>

</rss>
```

Answer (score 1):

"Under //rss:rss/channel" means below the `<channel>` tag that is below the `<rss>` tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <link rel="hub" href="https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" />
    </channel>
</rss>
```